# Print format using c

Tags: c, printing, format

```
                            1
                            *

               2                            3
              **                           ***

   4                        5                        6
 ****                     *****                    ******
```

How to print this format in C.Write a program using loops to show the output.For example if i enter the number 6 it would show the output above.
Thanks

```
main()
{
int n, c, k, space, count = 1;

printf("Enter number of rows\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

space = n;

for ( c = 1 ; c <= n/2 ; c++)
{
    for( k = 1 ; k < space ; k++)
       printf(" ");

    for ( k = 1 ; k <= c ; k++)
    {
        printf("%d",c);

        if ( c > 1 && count < c)
        {
             printf(" ");    
             count++; 
        }      
    }    

    printf("\n");
    space--;
    count = 1;
}
return 0;
```

}

its giving me

```
     1
    2 2
   3 3 3
```

Comment: What you have tried? Show your effort. Don't ask for a complete solution in SO.

Comment: `puts("                           1
                            *

               2                            3
              **                           ***

   4                        5                        6
 ****                     *****                    ******");`  with the needed spaces and 9 or so `\n`

Comment: i need to it using loop @chux

Comment: @vipulsinghal Better to include _all_ requirements in the post.  (You can edit it) than commenting about them, maybe one at a time.  Even better to show what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

i can help you with the basic logic part
consider $ loops
for(i=0;i<3;i++) this loop will print 3 rows
then s loop which will print space on the upper right hand size
j loop for printing your desired output
r loop for printing on right hand of the loop
and then printf("\n");